# No empty entries in hash table using linear probing?

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

I am trying to understand and implement hash tables using linear probing. While searching for an implementation I have come across this piece of code for a search method:

```
struct DataItem *search(int key) {
   //get the hash 
   int hashIndex = hashCode(key);

   //move in array until an empty 
   while(hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL) {

      if(hashArray[hashIndex]->key == key)
         return hashArray[hashIndex];

      //go to next cell
      ++hashIndex;

      //wrap around the table
      hashIndex %= SIZE;
   }

   return NULL;        
}
```

What I don't understand is if all the entries in the hashArray are already occupied by a key, shouldn't the while loop become infinite? or does this never happen? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, this implementation will get stuck in a loop if all the cells are already full and `key` does not exist in the table. Here is the implementation that should work:

```
struct DataItem *search(int key) {
   //get the hash 
   int initialHashIndex = hashCode(key) % SIZE;

   //move in array until an empty 
   int hashIndex = initialHashIndex;
   while(hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL) {    
      if(hashArray[hashIndex]->key == key)
         return hashArray[hashIndex];

      //go to next cell
      ++hashIndex;

      //wrap around the table
      hashIndex %= SIZE;

      //check if all the items are checked
      if (hashIndex == initialHashIndex)
          break;
   }

   return NULL;        
}
```

However, strategies should be implemented to avoid letting a hash table's occupancy level to exceed a certain threshold. Keep in mind that the main purpose of a hash table is to **provide constant average (amortized) operations time**, independent of the number of elements stored in the hash. Therefore, if the hash table occupancy is high in a Linear Probing Hash, the search time will be a function of stored elements, which annihilates the main goal of using a hash.

Comment: Consider `int initialHashIndex = hashCode(key)%SIZE;` (add `%SIZE`) as hash code computations are often independent of the (current) hash table size.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if the all the entries in `hashArray` is occupied, this is an infinite loop. This code assumes that `hashArray` is never fully occupied.

A hash table that uses probing should have some minimum proportion of free slots, otherwise it will fall back to probing for many elements and the length of the probing might be very long. So there is another reason to ensure that the array is never fully occupied.

Presumably the code maintains a field containing the number of elements, in addition to `hashArray` and to the size of `hashArray`. This way, it can resize `hashArray` if the proportion of occupied slots goes over or below a certain fraction.